# Can I serialize an ACAccount object holding an authorized twitter account?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, acaccount

I have implemented the built in twitter API, and everything is working great, however I am trying to decide how best to persist a twitter account between sessions when a user has multiple twitter accounts set up.

If I only receive a single `ACAccount` using `-[ACAccountStore accountsWithAccountType:]`, this it's easy... I simply use that one. If, however, there are multiple `ACAccounts` I don't want to be asking them every time the enter the app which one to use.

The way I see it so far, my options are:

1. Serialize the `ACAccount` object using `NSKeyedArchiver` (this would be the ideal, if it is possible)
2. Bug the user every time (don't want to do this)
3. Store only the username of the selected `ACAccount`, then in the next session compare the username in each account within the `ACAccountStore`, and select that account (although for some reason this seems like an inelegant workaround).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: option (3) seems like the safest option. Serializing the ACAccount object in it's entirety is a bit like overkill. The only time you would ask following that is if they wish to change, or their twitter account name changes.

Comment: Thanks Petesh! Yeah, I've gone with #3 and it seems to work pretty solidly. I just didn't like the idea of relying solely on the username, but it works so I guess I'm happy.

Answer (score 4):

`ACAccount` has a property named [`identifier`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/ACAccount/identifier) to uniquely identify a single account. The type of that property is an `NSString` so you can persist its value easily with either `NSUserDefaults` or `NSCoding` (or whatever other persistence solution you use). When you want to retrieve the account that belongs to this identifier, you just use the method [-[ACAccountStore accountWithIdentifier:]](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Accounts/Reference/ACAccountStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ACAccountStore/accountWithIdentifier%3a) and pass the identifier as the parameter.